# How does a function that returns a Task<TResult> according to its signature not throw a compilation error when you return TResult?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

For example the following code compiles and runs fine even though the function signature clearly states that it returns a `Task<int>` not just an `int`.

```
public async Task<int> GetData(){
    return 1;
}
```

How does this work? It seems like C# is wrapping the `int` inside a "box" of sorts, but when I do something like this with a custom type it throws a compilation error.

Observe:

```
public async CustomType<int> GetData(){
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by custom type here ? Elaborate your question further

Comment: It obviously will generate an error. The compiler wont compile what it doesn't understand. You can use a `List<int>` or `IList<int>` or some other generic collections. Plus, since you have tagged `async-await`, I would also state that you have to wrap the return type into `Task` since its a convention. You cannot return return custom type from `async`.

Comment: I believe `Task` has special logic within the compiler - that's about as much as I know, though.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh524395.aspx

Comment: consider Task as operation rather than type, Task holds all asynchronous parameters which evaluate value on runtime

Answer (score 1):

The below code is also compile time error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' "

```
public Task<int> GetData(){
  return 1;
}
```

You would need to use `async` to return `int` as shown below. However, without any await it would give you warning - "This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread"

```
public async Task<int> GetData() {
        return 1;
}
```

To return task without `async` you would need to use TaskCompletionSource as shown below:

```
public  Task<int> GetData() {
        var result = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
        result.SetResult(1);
        return result.Task;
}
```